# How to track changes in file? macOS dev/swift

Tags: swift, macos

I need to track changes constantly (on the background) in one particular file and perform some action, when this file changes. How to do this? 
I consider using external lib, but preferably I would like to do this using Apple's tools.

Comment: You can use `fswatch` which you can install via **homebrew** with `brew install fswatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
    tail -f
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)